# CGEventPost is not working in (MacOS) launchd daemon

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard-events, xpc, launch-daemon

i want to simulate the keyboard with CGEventPost in the user session (MacOS).

```
CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, keyCode, down ) ;
CGEventPost( kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent ) ;
CFRelease( keyEvent ) ;
```

when i use this code in a normal app(whether run as root) , it works fine.

but when i run it in launchd-daemon like the project [smjobbless](https://github.com/aronskaya/smjobbless)  ,  it's not working.

here is my launch.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.bsd.SMJobBlessHelper</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.bsd.SMJobBlessHelper</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

the launchd-daemon project had been installed at `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools` success and everything is running OK （seems run as root） except the `CGEventPost` , it's very strange , any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daemon processes do not have access to the window session. UI events should be pushed back over the XPC channel to a process in the user's session (generally running as the user rather than root). If you want a launchd configuration, consider [LaunchAgents rather than LaunchDaemons](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Consider how this would work under [fast user switching](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/FastUserSwitching.html) when there are multiple active window sessions.

Directly to your question, in the above-linked docs, note:

> The Core Graphics framework relies on the presence of the window server and thus is available only to applications running in a login session.

Your daemon does not run in a login session.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day ,  i probably know how to improve my code

Comment: @RuiLiang if this answer helps you, please accept it and upvote, so others can see that it's a correct answer to the question asked